# Is there a site where I can play 30 seconds games?

Tags: online-chess, time-control, websites, bullet-chess

I only know, from the fastest time controls, which chess sites to play 1+0 and 0+1 on. But is there a possibility to play 30 second games?

Answer (score 10):

Not only does lichess.org has the option to berserk in 1m bullet-games, but after a recent update you are able to to start a 30sec game. You will learn nothing though.

Answer (score 5):

If you play on a tournament in http://lichess.org, you have the option to go into Berserk mode. This effectively halves your time (NOTE: not your opponent's), for the possibility of winning more points. If you're playing a 1 minute tournament, then berserking every game will allow you to effectively be playing 30 second games.

That being said, you won't learn much by playing 30 second games because the game will almost always come down to who's faster with the mouse as opposed to who's a faster thinker... but I'm assuming you already knew that.

**EDIT**: Since I originally wrote this, Lichess has implemented a stand-a-lone 30 second tournament mode. That is, both players are automatically forced to use 30 seconds for the whole game without having to berserk.

Answer (score 4):

chesscube.com allows you to play with any time you want even 10+1sec.
A fine bullet game with quality players can be played on chess.com but you have 1min option there.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: i already told that chesscube allow any time control. rest is suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The website http://chesstempo.com allows 10 seconds bullet games as the shortest possible.

Answer (score 1):

Chess.com now allows games down to 10 seconds and no increment. However, it's hard to find anyone playing faster times than the normal 60 second bullet. I just played a 10 second game after seeking for about two minutes.

I pulled this announcement off Facebook just now:

[image]

I tested how low the time control is allowed to be set. I found that the system seeks for a ten second game, but if you input 9 seconds as the time control, it will reject the input.

Answer (score 0):

On lichess you can play, 15 seconds chess as well, and there is lag compensation, for your unstable internet connection. Also if you premove, you do not lose anytime on your clock, as long as your premove is a legal move in the next position of the ongoing game.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in lichess.org.
First go to lichess main site and click on "Create a game". On the drop-down list, chose "realtime" and you can chose 1/2 minute which equals 30 seconds. Click "Create the game" and you all set!